# Is there any way in Spark to keep each stage's run time?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, hadoop

I am measuring the run-times of a spark job with different resource configurations and need to compare the run time of each stage. I can see them in UI only when the job is running.
I run my job on a Hadoop cluster and use Yarn as the resource manager.

Is there any way to keep each stage's run-time? Is there any log for them?

**UPDATE:**

I read the monitoring document which is mentioned in the comment and add the following lines but it doesn't work:

in **spark-defaults.conf** :

```
spark.eventLog.enabled   true
spark.eventLog.dir    hdfs:///[nameNode]:8020/[PathToSparkEventLogDir]
spark.history.fs.logDirectory 
  hdfs:///[nameNode]:8020/[PathTosparkLogDirectory]
```

in **spark-env.sh**:

```
export SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS=[nameNode]
SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="-Dspark.eventLog.enabled=true"
SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS -Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=$sparkHistoryDir"
SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS -Dspark.history.provider=org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider"
SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS -Dspark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled=true"
SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS -Dspark.history.fs.cleaner.interval=7d"
```

It looks for */tmp/spark-events/* folder and when I create it and start the history server, it doesn't show any complete or incomplete application.

**Note** I tried the *logDirectory* value without port number too but it didn't work.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could run the Spark History Server and see the history of completed and incompleted applications by applying the following commands:

1. Set the public DNS value in **conf/spark-env.sh**

```
export SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS= NameNode-IP
```

2. Add these properties to SparkConf in my Java code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
                .set("spark.eventLog.dir", "hdfs:///user/[user-path]/sparkEventLog")
                .set("spark.history.fs.logDirectory", "hdfs:///user/[user-path]/sparkEventLog")
```

3. Create the property file ( *spark/conf/history.properties* ) containg the following lines

```
spark.eventLog.enabled  true
spark.eventLog.dir      hdfs:///user/[user-path]/sparkEventLog
spark.history.fs.logDirectory   hdfs:///user/[user-path]/sparkEventLog
```

4. Start the history server:

```
./sbin/start-history-server.sh --properties-file ./conf/history.properties
```

Note: The properties **eventLog.dir** and **eventLog.dir** should have the save values.